# How to add filename to cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to enter a filename to lookup account details in a file list, add them my active file, and then delete clear the cell with the file name.

I found this formula, which works when I enter in Excel.

In Excel:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))-1),"[","")
```

In VBA:

```vb
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Substitute(Left(CELL(""filename"",R1C1),Find(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R1C1))-1),""["","")"
```

VBA error:

> RUN-Time error '1004':
> Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: `"=Substitute(Left(CELL(""filename"",R1C1),Find(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R1C1))-1),""["","""")"` - you need to double up the last set of double quotes.

Comment: Oh thanks very much - I could have stared at that all day and not seen it